API internal error 500 in app and working fine in the server
When I try the API in the server I was working fine and response also comes but when I call that post API in my flutter app then it shows the 500 internal server error.
Is there is anything wrong in my code?
My API code:
Future<void> postData(Cart cart, Address selectedAddress) async {
  final url = 'https://api.vezigo.in/v1/orders';

  final body = {
    "items": cart.items.map((cartItem) {
      return {
        "pack": {
          "price": cartItem.price.toString(),
          "unit": cartItem.package,  
          "quantity": cartItem.quantity.toString(),
        },
        "product": cartItem.name,
        "quantity": cartItem.quantity
      };
    }).toList(),
    "billAmount": cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2),
    "userDetails": {
      "name": selectedAddress.yourName,
      "phoneNumber": selectedAddress.phoneNumber,
      "altPhoneNumber": selectedAddress.alternatePhoneNumber ,
      "address": "${selectedAddress.houseNumber}, ${selectedAddress.landmark}",
      "notes": selectedAddress.notes 
    },
    "geo": {
      "lat": selectedAddress.latitude.toString(),
      "lng": selectedAddress.longitude.toString()
    }
  };

  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');

  try {
    print('Request body: ${json.encode(body)}');
    print('Authorization: Bearer $accessToken');

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      },
      body: json.encode(body),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Response data: ${response.body}');
      _showOrderSuccessfulPopup(context);
    } else {
      // Log response for debugging
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Exception: $e');
  }
}

 
  void _showOrderSuccessfulPopup(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Image.asset('assets/payment/tick.png'),
          content: const Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Order Successful',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                'Your order #986547676 has been placed successfully!',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: AppColors.appbarColor,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 50, vertical: 15)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('Track my Order',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 18),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        side: const BorderSide(
                            color:AppColors.appbarColor, width: 1),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 70, vertical: 15)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Go Back',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.appbarColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }


and my print statement from API:

flutter: Request body: {"items":[{"pack":{"price":"36.0","unit":{"_id":"66d03fcc0273b734500c9eaf","quantity":1,"unit":"kg","price":36},"quantity":"1"},"product":"Aalu","quantity":1},{"pack":{"price":"100.0","unit":{"_id":"66d0400e0273b734500c9eb7","quantity":2,"unit":"kg","price":100},"quantity":"1"},"product":"Pyaaz","quantity":1},{"pack":{"price":"470.0","unit":{"_id":"66d041cc0273b734500c9ec6","quantity":3,"unit":"kg","price":470},"quantity":"1"},"product":"Fool Gobhi","quantity":1},{"pack":{"price":"1600.0","unit":{"_id":"66d045240273b734500c9ed4","quantity":5,"unit":"kg","price":1600},"quantity":"1"},"product":"Broccoli","quantity":1}],"billAmount":"2206.00","userDetails":{"name":"TAnu","phoneNumber":"9602046633","altPhoneNumber":"9602046633","address":"Basni, Basni","notes":"hello"},"geo":{"lat":"26.21638011850468","lng":"73.01504015922548"}}
flutter: Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NmVkMmRhMjliZGZlMTAwNmUzOTY5YWQiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjY4MTk3NzEsImV4cCI6MTcyNjgyMTU3MSwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.3Pg_GNqOv4jvdgl62xSX1ljlJSnCafs1HWEvtkEunv0
flutter: Error: 500
flutter: Response body: {"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","data":{}}


re check the token if it is expired or not .

Here are some suggestions:

Check the headers properly
Check the access token properly. Make sure that token isn't expired.
Check the request body again. Use ChatGPT to cross check.

If this still not work let me know.

Thank you so much it worked there was a problem in my body ,Thank you

You're Welcome.
